# Wordpress pretty permalinks fail over SSL - 404 File does not exist

Tags: django, wordpress, apache, ssl, php

I am unable to get wordpress pretty permalinks to work on an Ubuntu server with Apache, Django **and SSL**. The configuration works fine if I disable SSL, but fails with it enabled. With SSL enabled, every wordpress permalink (that doesn't map to a physical file) results in a 404 and an entry in apache's error log like

```
File does not exist: /var/www/wpwrap/wordpress/hello-world
```

I have tried dozens of stackoverflow & web suggested solutions (vast majority for non-SSL setups) - nothing has worked. I am seasoned with defining Apache configs (but not wordpress) and am admin of this machine.

**1. My apache setup**

- apache2.conf

  - basically out of the box, contains no `<Directory>` or `<VirtualHost>` entries
  - loads `conf.d/*` then `sites-enabled/*`
- httpd.conf (empty)
- sites-enabled/default-000

  - Out-of-the-box contents prior to this.  (My separate 443 vhost listed below redirects all http traffic to https, so this file should be moot). For troubleshooting this issue, I changed EVERY `<Directory>` entry in this file to explicitly contain these 2 lines. No effect.

    ```
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    ```
- conf.d/my-ssl-site.conf - My CORE configuration

  ```
  <Location /> 
  # preexisting, works fine
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          RewriteEngine on
          # force www prefix for plain example.com; 
          RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]
          # force ssl
          RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
          RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent]
      </IfModule>
  </Location>

  <VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName example.com
      ServerAlias www.example.com
      ServerAdmin admin@example.com
      DirectoryIndex index.html
      ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -f -l /var/log/django/error.log.%Y.%m.%d 25M"
      CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -f -l /var/log/django/access.log.%Y.%m.%d 25M" combined

  #FOR REWRITE DEBUGGING
      #RewriteLogLevel 10
      #RewriteLog /var/log/django/rewrites.log

  # =======   RUN DJANGO/PYTHON THROUGH WSGI MODULE OF APACHE ==============
  # pre-existing, works fine
      WSGIScriptAlias / /path_to_my/wsgi.py
      WSGIDaemonProcess example.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
      WSGIProcessGroup example.com

      SSLEngine on
      # additional SSL config stuff snipped from here

  # ==== WORDPRESS Settings
      Alias /blog /var/www/wpwrap/wordpress
      <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
          AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
          Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
          Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
          FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
      </IfModule>
      <Directory /var/www/wpwrap/wordpress>
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          DirectoryIndex index.php

          #pretty permalink setup, as defined by wordpress Admin UI 
          <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
              RewriteEngine On
              RewriteBase /blog/
              RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
              RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
          </IfModule>
      </Directory>

  #Added these directories during wordpress troubleshooting - no effect
      <Directory />
              Options FollowSymLinks
              AllowOverride All
      </Directory>
      <Directory /var/www/>
              Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
              AllowOverride All
              Order allow,deny
              allow from all
      </Directory>
      <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi>
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
      </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- There are no other `<Directory>` configs or `<VirtualHost>` configs or  `AllowOverride` lines in sites enabled, conf.d, or even in mods-enabled, anywhere within /etc/apache2.

**2. Server setup**

- Pre-existing, working config (running for a year)

  - Ubuntu 12.04
  - Apache 2.2.6 (mpm_worker NOT prefork)
  - Django (mod_wsgi)

    - Django serves base urls at /
  - mod_rewrite
  - virtualhost on 443 (mod_rewrite pushes all 80 traffic to 443), SSL certificate
- New for wordpress

  - wordpress 4.2.1 (to run side by side with pre-existing Django)

    - wordpress serves urls under /blog
    - wordpress files live at /var/www/wpwrap/wordpress
  - mod_fastcgi and php-fpm

    - Server performs well with worker mpm, so I installed well-documented solution (php-fpm & mod_fastcgi) to make PHP work with Apache worker mpm rather than downgrade Apache to prefork mpm just for wordpress.

**3. What works:**

- Pretty permalinks WITHOUT SSL (If I simply change vhost from 443->80)
- Wordpress Admin UI over SSL
- Any wordpress url that maps to a physically existent file
- Django, SSL, existing rewrites

**4. Other things Tried besides items noted above:**

No effect on the 404 and error with any of the following:

- Altering order of Virtual Host configuration (mod_wsgi above/below wordpress)
- Moving entire vhost settings into sites-enabled/default-ssl and reloading
- Playing with group (www-data) & permissions (775) of wordpress files
- Altering load order of conf.d/* and sites-enabled/*
- Beating my head against the wall :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

The problem was a conflict with the `<Location>` block, which contained another set of Rewrite Rules. Though the rules should not have collided (regex wise), somehow the Location rules were blocking execution of the Directory rules so they never ran at all.

Based on Apache docs which state that Rewrites are not officially supported in `<Location>` blocks, I migrated all `<Location>` rewrites into `<VirtualHost>` entries for ports 80 & 443 in my conf.d/my-ssl-site.conf file. Now everything works.

Comment: I have the same symptoms and cant follow your answer. My SSL conf is in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf Where is your location block?

Comment: I really want your solution to work but I fear it's not my cause. I moved from XAMPP to a native LAMP install. It's such a bizarre issue.

Comment: OK - I fixed it for me, and it was a simple solution, of course after hours of troubleshooting. I'll leave an answer since it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had all the same symptoms and found it was the SSL block in virtual hosts `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com.conf` `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` was missing a directory block...

```
    <Directory /var/www/html/mysite.com/public_html/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

As soon as I had that all permalinks off the home page started working :)